# In meteorJS, why is hideFinished written in different ways?

Tags: meteor

Html code-

```
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h1> TO DO</h1>
        <label class="hide-finished">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="{{hideFinished}}">
          Hide Finished Tasks
        </label>

JS code-

    Template.body.events({
            'Submit. new-task' : function(event){
                var title= event.target.title.value;
                Tasks.insert({
                    titile:title,
                    createdAt:new Date()
                });
                event.target.title.value="";
                return false;
            },
            'change.hide-finished':function(event){
                Session.set('hideFinished',event,target,checked);
            }
        });
```

Why is hide finished is written in two different ways?
As "hideFinished" and "hide-finished"?
Why in HTMl code it is written with "-" and in JS code it is written in camel case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression  `{{hideFinished}}` is calling a Template helper with that name. Somewhere in the body template should be some sort of helper defined like this:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  hideFinished () {
    // ... helper code
  }
})
```

It is usually used to compute some values that will be rendered into your template.

The second one is the name of the component on which an event is mapped to, in your case `.hide-finished` (allthough there needs to be a space between the event name and the selector, means `change .hide-finished` should be the correct name).

This event listens for the `change` event of an element with classname `hide-finished` and executes the defined function.

Note, that in your code you are currently listening to a change on a `label` element. In order to correctly capture the change it should be the `input` element.

```
<label>
  <input class="hide-finished" type="checkbox" checked="{{hideFinished}}">
  Hide Finished Tasks
</label>
```

A good start to read about how to use Templates in Meteor is the Blaze documentation, in your case especially these parts:

http://blazejs.org/#Quick-Start

http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html

http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps

Comment: Thank you. It was really useful.

Comment: I also highly suggest the meteor forums. You will receive really good help there.